# Confused about error handling in network layer when implementing MVVM in android, How to notify user something is wrong?

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, error-handling

I've been struggling with MVVM pattern and android-architecture-components for last couple of months.
In my last project although I did try to decouple some of my app logic but it ended with a lot of code mess. Every fragment did lots of work, from handling UI to handling network requests and ... 
In this new App I followed best practices for android app architecture and till now it's going well. But the thing is, I don't know how to handle network errors, and I don't get it how should I notify user if some network calls fail.

After searching and reading some blog posts I ended up with the following code (SafeApiCall and SafeApiResutl) functions to handle network requests in one place, but the thing is, All my Network Requests are done using retrofit and a NetworkDataSource class, Then I pass The NetworkDataSource and Dao to the RepositoryImpl class which is an implementation of my Repository Interface. then I pass the Repository to the viewModel, So ViewModel knows nothing about network or Dao or what so ever. So here is the problem, How can I notify user in case of any network errors ? I thought about creating a LiveData<> and pass errors to it in network layer, but in this case, Repository Must observe this, and also let's say create a LiveData in repository so viewModel observe that and so on ... But this is too much chaining, I dont like the idea of doing that. I also did take a look at the GoogleSamples Todo-MVVM-live-kotlin project, but honestly I didn't understand what is going on.

```
    suspend fun <T : Any> safeApiCall(call: suspend () -> Response<BasicResponse<T>>, errorMessage: String): T? {
        return when (val result = safeApiResult(call)) {
            is NetworkResult.Success -> {
                Timber.tag("safeApiCall").d("data is ${result.serverResponse.data}")
                result.serverResponse.data
            }
            is NetworkResult.Error -> {
                Timber.tag("SafeApiCall").e("$errorMessage & Exception - ${result.exception}")
                null
            }
            else -> TODO()
        }
    }
```

```
    private suspend fun <T : Any> safeApiResult(
        call: suspend () -> Response<BasicResponse<T>>
    ): NetworkResult<T> {
        return try {
            val response = call.invoke()
            Timber.tag("SafeApiResult")
                .d("response code : ${response.code()}, server value : ${response.body()!!.status}, server message: ${response.body()!!.message}")
            if (response.isSuccessful) {
                return when (ServerResponseStatus.fromValue(response.body()!!.status)) {
                    ServerResponseStatus.SUCCESS -> NetworkResult.Success(response.body()!!)
                    ServerResponseStatus.FAILED -> TODO()
                    ServerResponseStatus.UNKNOWN -> TODO()
                }
            } else {
                TODO()
            }
        } catch (exception: Exception) {
            Timber.tag("SafeApiResultFailed").e(exception)
            NetworkResult.Error(exception)
        }

    }
```

```
    sealed class NetworkResult<out T : Any> {
        data class Success<out T : Any>(val serverResponse: BasicResponse<out T>) : NetworkResult<T>()
        data class Error(val exception: Exception) : NetworkResult<Nothing>()
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are in the correct path. I would place both methods in the `NetworkDataSource`. All the calls executed should call those methods to handle the errors.

The `NetworkDataSource` will return the NetworkResult to the repository, and it will return the result to the ViewModel.

As you say, you can use a LiveData to notify the Activity/Fragment. You can create an error data class:

```
data class ErrorDialog(
   val title: String, 
   val message: String
)
```

And declare a `LiveData<ErrorDialog>` that will be observed from your view. Then when you receive notifications in your view, you can implement logic in a `BaseActivity`/`BaseFragment` to show a `Dialog` or `Toast` or whatever type of view to indicate the error.